# Django Form Javascript read Boolean field

Tags: javascript, django, forms

In my models.py I have

```
urgency = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False, verbose_name="Hitno otklanjanje")
```

And I wish to run a javascript function to change a text field depending on 'True' or 'False' on that Boolean field. Problem is, I can't get the value. When I use `document.getElementById('id_urgency').value;` I always get 'on', no matter of clickbox check. Why is that? I guess I'm reading the value wrong? Or?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function makeReadOnly()
             {
              var a = document.getElementById('id_urgency').value;
              console.log(a);

              if (document.getElementById('id_urgency').value == 'True'){
                  document.getElementById('id_date_days').readOnly = true;
             }else if (document.getElementById('id_urgency').value == 'False'){
                  document.getElementById('id_date_days').readOnly = false;
              }
             }
         document.getElementById('id_urgency').addEventListener('change', makeReadOnly);
```

This is a part of django form. If I go to 'inspect' on that page, that Checkbox doesn't even have value, why is that?

```
input type="checkbox" name="urgency" class="checkboxinput form-check-input" id="id_urgency"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `.value`, you get the value attached to that checkbox, not whether the checkbox is checked or not.

You can check if a checkbox is checked with:

```
var a = document.getElementById('id_urgency').checked;
```

or as specified by [*javascripttutorial.net*](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-checkbox/):

> To check if the accept checkbox is checked, you use the following
> code:
>
> ```
> const cb = document.getElementById('accept');
> console.log(cb.checked);
> ```
>
> (…)
>
> If you get the value attribute of a checkbox, **you always get the `'on'`** string whether the checkbox is checked or not. For example:
>
> ```
> const cb = document.getElementById('accept');
> console.log(cb.value); // on
> ```